# Subclipse > Accidental Merge Conflict Resolution

Tags: svn, subclipse

I'm trying to merge changes from one branch into another using Subclipse. On a particular file in a particular subdirectory, I had a file conflict and edited the conflicts via the context menu option for this. However, when I went to resolve the conflict I apparently chose the wrong option and was left with the original unmerged file in my branch.

Since then, I can no longer get this file back into a conflicted state so I can resolve this issue properly. I've tried deleting the file and the directory that contains it, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just roll back to the pre-merge revision and do it again?

Comment: I tried getting the original version of the file from the repository. I also tried replacing the entire directory. 

A colleague suggested that I commit the bad "resolved" version, then roll it back.